# Set viewController shared public object

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I've got `ViewController` that contains `tableView` and an array of items to be displayed on that table.

In order to change table content, I could initialise the array and calling reloadData method from within ViewController button callback (see `buttonTap` method below).

However, I also need to change the table contents from external code outside the scope of `viewController`, but it's inaccessible.

In the minimal example below I'm using external C/C++ based thread that unsuccessfully attempts to access a `viewController` method but it fails on compilation due to `No known class method for selector 'changeArr'`

Any idea how to make viewController public ?

viewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController() <NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource>

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;
@property NSMutableArray<NSString*> * arr;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear {
    [super viewWillAppear];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return self.arr.count;
}

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

    NSTableCellView* cellView =(NSTableCellView*)[tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"cell1" owner:nil];
    cellView.textField.stringValue = self.arr[row];
    return cellView;
}

-(void)changeArr {
    self.arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"ccc", @"ddd", nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"fwefwe");
}

- (IBAction)buttonTap:(id)sender {

    self.arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"AAAA", @"BBB", nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

main.m

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

void updateTable() {
    sleep(10);    
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [ViewController changeArr]; });  // ERROR : No known class method for selector 'changeArr'
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // Setup code that might create autoreleased objects goes here.
    }

    pthread_t threadHandler;
    pthread_create(&threadHandler, NULL, &updateTable, NULL);

    return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: Objective-C is very different language from C++.

Comment: Taking into account *how* you're trying to do, it will be very helpful for you to start from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/index.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`changeArr` is a private function(-). So you can't call `[ViewController changeArr]`.
If you change `changeArr` to public fuction(+), it's impossible to access internal array.
So I think the easy way to do this task is using a instance of `ViewController` by singletone.

```
    ...
    @implementation ViewController
    + (id) sharedViewController {
        static ViewController *sharedInstance = nil;
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
            sharedInstance = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewControllerIdentifier"];
        });
        return sharedInstance ;
    }

   - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   ...
```

and in updateTable:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [[ViewController sharedViewController]  changeArr]; });
```